# How to access web site with revoked security certificate in IE11

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, internet-explorer, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I am debugging an issue for Internet Explorer 11 and have loaded up my dev URL in the browser, this works fine in Mozilla Firefox but in IE (and Chrome) I am getting an 'Website security certificate' warning (shown below) and cannot access the site (but can do fine with the same URL in Firefox).

Can anyone explain how to fix this?

Note - I am using Windows 10 (upto-date)

[image]

e.g https://me.dev-01.mycompany.com/

Comment: You could temporarily disable certificate revocation checking under IE settings > Advanced Tab > "Check for server certificate revocation" tickbox.

Comment: Replace the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome and Microsoft's browsers (Edge and Internet Explorer) are using Windows' certificate management system. Firefox uses its own certificate management system. That's answer why Firefox works fine.

According to the help page, this error stands for (formatted by me):

> 1. the security certificate was obtained or used fraudulently by the website.
> 2. The encryption key that is specified in the certificate might have been compromised or the user listed in a certificate does not have authority to use it (for example, the company was sold).
> 3. The certification authority that issued the certificate keeps a list of revoked certificates and that list is checked by Internet Explorer.

([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20090529194855/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/About-certificate-errors)).

We know that [1] isn't that case (Firefox OK with this certificate) and as long as Firefox is up to date, [2] should not happen. Therefore, we'll assume that this certificate is not safe [3] and Firefox just in a delay and will revoke it.

**What should you do?** If you can, try lookup this certificate's `CA` and find a reason for this revoke. If you think it's a mistake, you can add this `CA` (In chrome: Settings > Show advanced settings > HTTPS/SSL > Manage Certificates > Authorities > Import). However, I would **not** do that and just register another certificate from another `CA`.